# Sequelize query with where and or operator

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

'SELECT * FROM ng_db.public."Transactions"
WHERE credited_account = 1 OR debited_account = 1;'

How to do this query in sequelize?

I need a return that shows me the lines about a value that can be present in two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#applying-where-clauses), you should use `[Op.or]`

You should check the [operator documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators), it's really usefull

```js
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

YourTable.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      { credited_account: 1 },
      { debited_account: 1 }
    ]
  }
});
```